# How does the order of the pairs of cross-links in DNA determine the arrangement of the amino acids?

Tags: dna, proteins, amino-acids, protein-interaction

Quoting Richard Feynman from Chapter 3 of his book Six Easy Pieces, when he talks about DNA:

> Attached to each sugar along the line, and linking the two chains together, are certain parts of cross-links. However, they are not all of the same kind; there are four kinds, called adenine, thymine, cytosine, and guanine, but let us call them A, B, C, and D.
>
> ...
>
> Next comes the question, precisely how does the order of the A, B, C, D units determine the arrangement of the amino acids in the protein? This is the central unsolved problem in biology today.

Feynman taught his lectures during 1961-1963. Do we now know how does the order of adenine, thymine, cytosine and guanine affect the order of the amino acids in the DNA?

Comment: I have found that starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful to learn about an unfamiliar area. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was solved in the early 1960s, starting about 1961.  See [Wikipedia's Genetic Code - History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#History), and perhaps "[Establishing the Triplet Nature of the Genetic Code](https://www.cell.com/cell/fulltext/S0092-8674(07)00253-X?_returnURL=https%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS009286740700253X%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)".